# Is this code dereferencing a pointer or doing something else?

Tags: shared-ptr

I've never seen this kind of thing before - I'm a little new to shared_ptr - is this a typical operation with a shared pointer, or is someone doing something a little fancy here?  It doesn't seem like a dereference - it looks more like someone's trying to make sure the operator->() is defined...

I've done a google/duckduckgo on this in as many ways as I can think of, can't find any good examples online.

Thanks.

```
void fn(std::shared_ptr<int> data){
if(data.operator->() == NULL){
return; //this is an error
}

....//rest of function, doesn't matter

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```
T* operator->() const noexcept;
```

you are accessing internal pointer of `shared_ptr`. If it is not NULL you can read data pointed by this pointer. To do it you must use:

```
T& operator*() const noexcept;
```

So when you want to check if `shared_ptr` points some data and read it, you could write:

```
void fn(std::shared_ptr<int> data) {
    if(data.operator->() == NULL) // dereference pointer
       return; //this is an error

    int value = data.operator*(); // dereference data pointed by pointer
}
```

The code above is rather fancy way of using `shared_ptr` instances. Instead of calling operators like member functions - `obj.operator @()` you can use shorter form by applying `@obj`:

```
 // this code does the same thing as above
void fn2(std::shared_ptr<int> data)
{
    if(!data)
       return; //this is an error

    int value = *data;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

For more details, [see reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*).